# How to fetch existing lambda function from aws to local system using serverless or any other options?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, aws-serverless

I am using AWS lambda and for the first couple of weeks I created lambda function using AWS console, but after some time I found Serverless. So I set up Serverless on my local system and now whenever I need to create any lambda function, I use Serverless and deploy.

My question is how can I get the previous lambda functions which I have created using AWS console. Is it possible to fetch existing function using Serverless or any alternative solution?

Please suggest.

Thanks
Biswajit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export that from AWS Console either as a SAM File or Deployment package as follows

Login to AWS Console -> Navigate to Lambda home page -> Select the Lambda that you want locally -> Click Actions -> Select 'Export Function'

As well you can use [get-function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-function.html) via AWS CLI